# How to update SQL from one row in Excel to one SQL register at once

Tags: sql, excel

My first post at stackoverflow! I just started to work with SQL, and I need help with the code to update a SQL table taking data from Excel. I already have the connection successfully done, and it is updating fine one by one cell from Excel to the corresponding fields in the SQL database, my question is how can I update from one full row of data in Excel to one full new “row” in a SQL table? without doing it one by one.

Part of my code is:

```
reg.AddNew
reg!Field1= sheet1.Cells(2, "H").Value
reg.Update
```

and I have too many H cells to do it one by one, and it is not elegant:

What would be the code just to add the full new SQL row at once?

I think it would be something like:

```
reg.AddNew
(SQL Side ?????????) = Sheet1.Range(“H2:GT2”) 
reg.Update
```

Unfortunately, I cannot publish the full code.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks to all the programmer warriors that apply their time voluntarily to help here!